# Selecting text in TextinputCell in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I use a TextInputCell in a CellTable. When I click on a cell, I would like the text to be selected. I don't want this to be an EditTextCell.

Have you any idea?

Comment: I think it's clear what this question is about. I don't understand all the close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
myTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<MyObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<MyObject> event) {
        if ("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            if (event.getColumn() == table.getColumnIndex(myColumn)) {
                InputElement input = (InputElement) getRowElement(event.getIndex()).getCells().getItem(event.getColumn()).getFirstChildElement().getFirstChildElement();
                input.select();
            }
        }
    }
});
```